# Are desktop PC ports less durable in terms of mating cycles than laptop ports?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, ports

I have an HP EliteDesk 800 Mini PC, and I am using it like a laptop in the sense that I take it to and from work every day.

[image: HP EliteDesk 800 Mini PC]

At home and at work I have a power adapter, monitor, keyboard, and mouse that I connect to the mini PC. By my rough calculations that means the power jack, DisplayPort, and rear USB ports will see 1,200 to 1,500 mating cycles in the next two years (after two years I envisage upgrading to whatever new and improved thing HP come out with).

I have searched far and wide to determine if a mini PC can withstand this kind of use. Durability of the ports and ESD protection come to mind. I have found nothing concrete at all, not even from HP (still waiting for their reply after a few days).

Is there any evidence that desktop ports are less durable than laptop ports? I am looking for specific expertise or specifications from the industry, not personal opinion.

If so, is there a number of possible cycles that I can expect?

Comment: I have a not-that-mini PC (around 20x20x10 cm) that worked 24x7 for over two years and seems it's still working fine.  If the environment is not dusty it should be fine.  Just a little suggestion: you can use a short USB extension cable that is always plugged into your mini-PC to prolong the USB port's life.

Comment: Asking about form factor as the driver may be the wrong question.  All else being equal, the service life is based on the quality of the parts, which is reflected in device price.  What you're asking is, when manufacturers build devices, do some of them skimp and use crappy parts for one form factor over another when they think that form factor may not require as reliable a component.  That practice would be manufacturer specific.  You can't make industry-wide generalizations.

Comment: @fixer1234 You make a good point, indeed design choices are often manufacturer and model specific (in the absence of standards or regulation). And I'd be surprised if a manufacturer was willing to disclose their internal durability targets/test results. However there may be hope, I didn't think of searching for DisplayPort/USB standards/specifications. Perhaps durability requirements are in there somewhere...

Comment: Not an "answer", but a solution. Buy 0.5 or 0.8 foot USB extension cables, and leave them plugged in permanently. Now you will cycle the port on the device only a few times throughout its lifetime, and can buy a new pack of cables if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several relevant points.

**Form Factor**
Form factor is not a driving variable.  All else being equal, the service life is based on the quality of the parts, which is reflected in device price.  Specific manufacturers could theoretically use better or worse quality parts for different form factor hardware, assuming that one form factor needs to stand up to more usage than another.  This would not be an industry-wide practice.  So you couldn't generalize based on form factor.

A much bigger influence than form factor would be intended usage/price point.  Equipment designed for military or field use will be much more durable than equipment designed for business use, which will be more durable than equipment designed to compete on price in the home consumer market.

**Standards and Specifications**
When there **are** specifications on components like connectors, they are for things like insertion cycles under proper use.  This addresses characteristics like whether the plating will wear off the contacts.  These ratings far exceed anything the connector will see in normal usage over the expected service life of the device it is in; these specs are easy to meet because even crappy connectors won't wear out from normal use.

Connectors fail due to damage or abuse, and quality of construction is what provides protection.  Individual components don't have damage-resistance specs like drop tests because the device case and how the component is mounted and protected drives damage risk.  Drop tests and the like are for the complete device.  There is also no way to spec or test the various ways a connector could get damaged.

This gets back to how well-made the connector is in ways that can be described in terms of the materials and construction but can't be easily specified or tested in terms of the results.  These characteristics are reflected in the component cost and ultimately in the device cost.

Comment: This is as good an answer as we'll get. I spent more time researching and came to exactly the same conclusion. Looks like I'm stuck personally field-testing my mini-PC. Lets see how durable it is over the coming months!